# Backup tablet before repair

Tags: backup

My son received an asus tablet for his birthday last year and has now told me the screen does not work completely (some areas are dead to the touch). I have told him we will send it for repair but he is worried that when it comes back they will have reset it and he will have lost all his apps, videos, photos, programs etc. Can anyone tell me how I back it up so that when it comes back I can just put all the information back on so that it is exactly as it is now. Please can any answers be as easy to understand as possible

Comment: @DanB probably not – which is why bmdixon pointed that out :) Forgive him for the phrasing, that was the system (auto-comment). // **Paul:** You can find additional details in our [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info). Many of our tags have a wiki page associated where you can find first-aid and useful links on their topic. Good luck with backup, repair and restore!

Comment: @Izzy alright then.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of non app data, just plug it in to a computer, and move it over. Just go to your device in an file manager/explorer, and copy the pictures, DCIM, Download and Music folders to your pc. Then, if needs be, you can copy them back.

App data will be different. Assuming you have a Google account, just sign in to it again when you get it back(if it has been reset), and it will re-download the apps automatically. If they have cloud save (most games do) it will re-download his progress.

Answer (score 0):

1.It is possible to take backup of your Full Tablet, But For that you need to root your tablet.

2.Because if your rooted your tablet it is possible to take every app+data with that backup.

3.But make sure your are not void the warranty, Because rooting will void your warranty.